# Oracle After Trigger Error:ORA-24344

Tags: oracle

Hi I'm trying to implement a trigger into my database but I'm facing a really strange problem the error ORA-24344 keeps occurring I've tried to research the issue but I seem to be going in circles anyone with more knowledge can point me in the right direction

```
  CREATE or Replace TRIGGER project_trigger1
  BEFORE INSERT or update on project
  FOR EACH ROW
  begin
  IF (:new.project_type = 'Conservation') and (:new.EXTERNAL_SPONSER is
   null)
    then rasie_application_error(-20009, 'External sponsor field must
    be completed.');
    END IF;
    IF (:new.project_type = 'Conservation') and
     (:new.CONSERVATION_CLASS is null)
     then rasie_application_error(-200010, 'conservation class fieldmust be completed.');END IF;
     IF (:new.project_type = 'Conservation') and
      (:new.IMPACT_ANALYSIS_REQUIRED is null)
      then rasie_application_error(-200011, 'impact_analysis field must
      be completed.');
     END IF; 
      IF (:new.project_type = 'Conservation') and
      (:new.PROJECT_LOCATION_TYPE is   null)
     then rasie_application_error(-200002, 'project location type field
     must be     completed.');
     END IF; 
     END;
```

Comment: can you compile the trigger in `sqlplus` and then check errors via `show errors` ?

Comment: yeah line 1           CREATE or Replace TRIGGER project_trigger1

Comment: You have written "ra**sie**_application_error" instead of "ra**ise**_application_error".
A part from this issue, the code seems correct.

Comment: thanks for that had a long week